# BeautifulSoup scraping nested tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have been trying to scrape the data from a website which is using a good amount of tables.  I have been researching on the beautifulsoup documentation as well as here on stackoverflow but am still lost.

Here is the said table:

```html
      <form action="/rr/" class="form">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" align="left">
          <tr bgcolor="#6699CC">
            <td valign="top"><font face="arial"><b>Uesless Data</b></font></td>
    
            <td width="10%"><br /></td>
    
            <td align="right"><font face="arial">Uesless Data</font></td>
          </tr>
    
          <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
            <td> <input size="12" name="s" value="data:" onfocus=
            "this.value = '';" /> <input type="hidden" name="d" value="research" />
        
            <input type="submit" value="Date" /></td>
    
            <td width="10%"><br /></td>
    
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    
      <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table><br />
      <br />
    
      <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="99%">
            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
              <tr bgcolor="#A0B8C8">
                <td colspan="6"><b>Data to be pulled</b></td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
                <td><font face="arial"><b>Data to be pulled</b></font></td>
    
                <td><font face="arial"><b>Data to be pulled</b></font></td>
    
                <td align="center"><font face="arial"><b>Data to be pulled
                </b></font></td>
    
                <td align="center"><font face="arial"><b>Data to be pulled
                </b></font></td>
    
                <td align="center"><font face="arial"><b>Data to be pulled
                </b></font></td>
    
                <td align="center"><font face="arial"><b>Data to be pulled
                </b></font></td>
              </tr>
    
              <tr>
                <td>Data to be pulled</td>
    
                <td align="center">Data to be pulled</td>
    
                <td align="center">Data to be pulled</td>
    
                <td align="center">Data to be pulled</td>
    
                <td align="center"><br /></td>
              </tr>
         </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
      </table>
```

There are quite a few tables, and none of which really have any distinguishing id's or tags.  My most recent attempt was:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'border':'0', 'width': "100%'})
```

Which is pulling only the first empty table.  I feel like the answer is simple, and I am over thinking it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If it's just finding all 4 tables with (a superset of) these attrs, use `find_all` instead of `find`. Is that all you wanted?

Comment: Meanwhile, if every table on the page has the same `border` and `width`, these attrs aren't really doing you any good. It's just as brittle as if you just did `soup.find_all('table')`. And there's really no good way to be any _less_ brittle on a 90s-style page like this. You could try to do fancy things like only find `table`s that are underneath some other particular chain of tags and so on, and hope that they never change the page layout, but usually that's not worth doing if the simple thing is returning the right results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking for all of the tables, rather than the first one, you just want `find_all` instead of `find`.

If you're trying to find a particular table, like the one nested inside another one, and the page is using a 90s-style design that makes it impossible to find it via `id` or other attrs, the only option is to search by structure:

```
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for subtable in table.find_all('table'):
        # Found it!
```

And of course you can flatten this into a single comprehension if you really want to:

```
subtable = next(subtable for table in soup.find_all('table') 
                for subtable in table.find_all('table'))
```

Notice that I left off the `attrs`. If every table on the page has a superset of the same attrs, you aren't helping anything by specifying them.

This whole thing is obviously ugly and brittle… but there's really no way *not* to be brittle with this kind of layout.

Using a different library, like `lxml.html`, that lets you search by XPath might make it a little more compact, but it's ultimately going to be doing the same thing.

Comment: The layout was making it very difficult to find without any definitive `id`.

I'm trying to get the td information from the nested table.  Searching by structure is what I was thinking I needed to do, I just didnt know how.  I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @user2259786: Yes, table-within-table-within-table layouts with no `id`s anywhere and so on make it hard to extract data simply, efficiently, or robustly; that's why it's called "90s style", because most people figured out to stop doing that 15 years ago. :) But if you have to deal with a page that's still done old-style, you have to do clunky old-style searching.